# Regression Model in c#

Tags: graph, regression

I am working with ZedGraph and I also tried MsCharts tool. If I have a function y = 2X (it is a line in 2D) then I am easily showing the line in ZedGraph or MsCharts using a pair (x,y). But the question is how to show a function like this z = 2X + Y. How can I show this in a graph. Is there a tool to do it in 3D. In ZedGraph and as far as I understood, in MsCharts is not possible to do this.

Do you have any idea? Thnx a lot for reading and helping :). As you can see both are regression models

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/zedgraph/wiki/Home/):

> ZedGraph is a class library, user control, and web control for .net, written in C#, for drawing 2D Line, Bar, and Pie Charts. It features full, detailed customization capabilities, but most options have defaults for ease of use.

It seems ZedGraph is 2D only. Maybe look at something like [GNUPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) instead.

Comment: I had a look on it and it doesnt work for c# :S. I tried to integrate Matlab with c# and then i was sending all my data to matlab function x = [1 2 3], Y= [2 3 4], Z = [5 6 7] and then I was able to show it in 3D. The problem is that I need to redraw it in every iteration and it takes too much time :S.